# How to build a string with UTF characters in C++ (QT framework)

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to construct a string (QString) made up of 'bullets' (black small circle, U+2022).

Anyone know how I'd do this?

Thanks in advance,
Wes

eg: "* * * * * *" but bullets instead of asterisks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a single black bullet by using:

```
QString::fromUtf8( "\u2022" );
```

You can string some of those together to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
QString circle(L"\u2022");
```

Comment: Or if you want 5 bullets: `QString circles(5, QChar(0x2022));`

Answer (score 0):

Is is not the syntax like.

new QString(L"**");

And ensure that your source file is UTF-8 encoded?

Sorry I can't try that myself.

Comment: In C++, `new` isn't that common.

Comment: Thats right, RAII is the way to go.  However I used new here to show that a new QString was getting constructed.